# Error 'Cannot set property 'checked' of undefined' with jquery.rating

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to incorporate jquery.rating into a form but I get an error when I press the 'erase' button and I am not sure if this is a bug or I am doing something wrong. I am working with the latest version.

This code reproduces the error (make sure to download the .zip file of [jquery.rating](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/) and expand it in a folder called 'starrate'):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">


</head>

<body>

<script src='starrate/jquery.js' type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

<script src='starrate/jquery.MetaData.js' type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
<script src='starrate/jquery.rating.js' type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
<link href='starrate/jquery.rating.css' type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />



<form action="#" method="post" class="stdform" id="ratingform">


<input type="radio" class="starrate" name="the_rating" value="1" id="rate1" title="choice 1" />
<input type="radio" class="starrate" name="the_rating" value="2" id="rate2" title="choice 2" /> 
<input type="radio" class="starrate" name="the_rating" value="3" id="rate3" title="choice 3" checked="checked" /> 
<input type="radio" class="starrate" name="the_rating" value="4" id="rate4" title="choice 4" /> 
<input type="radio" class="starrate" name="the_rating" value="5" id="rate5" title="choice 5" />

<span id="choice" style="margin:0 0 0 20px;">choice 0</span>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#ratingform input:radio[name="the_rating"]').rating({
            focus: function(value, link){
                var tip = $('#choice');
                tip[0].data = tip[0].data || tip.html();
                tip.html(link.title || 'value: '+value);
            },
            blur: function(value, link){
                if ( !this.checked ) {
                    var tip = $('#choice');
                    $('#choice').html(tip[0].data || '');
                }
            }, 
            callback: function(value, link){
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Everything is working fine, except when I press the 'delete'-button to the left of the stars. In Crome I get `Cannot set property 'checked' of undefined`, in IE9 I get a dutch error message which means roughly the same (SCRIPT5007: Kan de waarde van de eigenschap checked niet instellen: het object is null of niet gedefinieerd).

They both point to the same line of code in jquery.rating.js, which is "$(input)[0].checked=true;". Here is a piece of the code:

```
[...]
        // Update rating control state
        this.data('rating', control);
        // Update display
        this.rating('draw');
        // find data for event
        var input = $( control.current ? control.current.data('rating.input') : null );
        // change selection - required since 1.9, see http://code.google.com/p/jquery-star-rating-plugin/issues/detail?id=123
ERROR:      $(input)[0].checked=true;
```

Anybody got an idea about what is going on here?

Comment: My guess would be input is undefined, and undefined doesn't have a checked property. That line could be simplified to `input.checked=true`, but it would still have the same problem. If you changed it to `$(input).prop("checked",true)` it will work because jQuery will see that there are no elements to act on.

Comment: I have made my first steps at debugging with Chrome. The variable control.current turns out to be null, so input becomes null, with results in: $(null)[0].checked=true. Thanks @KevinB I changed the line to $(input).prop("checked",true) in case input might also have valid values. I will report this as a bug.

Comment: I reported it as a bug and they immediately fixed it. Nice